# How does Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate work on instance members?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, marshalling, unsafe

I am wondering about Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate. Namely I want to know how it converts a delegate to a function that is non static into a function pointer.

Does it dynamically generate a code stub that has the instance attached somehow? And if so, doesn't this leak memory? Perhaps the delegate frees it in its finalizer?

It doesn't look like System.Delegate has a finalizer, so I am very interested in how this mechanism works. I would assume that it would take 4 bytes for the function pointer and 4 bytes for the instance (on 32-bit), yet it returns a simple IntPtr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Big question, delegates have an iceberg of code associated with them in the CLR.  So just some hints.  Download the [SSCLI20 distribution](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917) to look at the source.  All relevant code is in the clr/src/vm subdirectory.

UMEntryThunk is the wrapper for a thunk that marshals the call.  It is created by COMDelegate::ConvertToCallback() in comdelegate.cpp, called by MarshalNative::GetFunctionPointerForDelegateInternal(), the internal implementation of the Marshal method.

A pointer to UMEntryThunk is stored in the syncblk for the delegate object, syncblk.h, InteropSyncBlockInfo::SetUMEntryThunk() method.

When the garbage collector destroys the delegate object, it also cleans up the syncblk for it and that invokes the ~InteropSyncBlockInfo destructor.  Which calls the UMEntryThunk::FreeUMEntryThunk() method which cleans up the thunk again.

So, no, there is no memory leak.  Not exactly a finalizer, just part of the normal GC cleanup.

Comment: Aha, and it looks like it generates code that passes a UMEntryThunk * in eax then calls the stub that is generated in GenerateUMThunkPrestub, cgenx86.cpp. This in turn extracts the thunk from eax and does the actual call. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: Link is no longer active, I guess it should be updated to https://github.com/dotnet/runtime