# pass interface from c# to rust

Tags: c#, rust, ffi

I would like to define a function in rust that can accept (by-reference) something implementing a C# interface (in this case, `Serilog`'s `ILogger` interface, but ideally this would work for any arbitrarily chosen interface). My intent is to have a C# frontend call into a (possibly long-running) rust backend, passing perhaps a handful of data, among which is at least one interface - the ILogger.

So far, I've been able to pass a pointer to the `ILogger.Write` method directly, rather than passing the object itself. (following [Passing a C# instance method to Rust as a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800598/passing-a-c-sharp-instance-method-to-rust-as-a-callback))

C#:

```cs
const string dll = "...";

[DllImport(dll)]
static extern void foo_fn(IntPtr log, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string input);

public delegate void LogFunc(LogEventLevel level, string message);
public static void FooFn(LogFunc log, string input)
{
    foo_fn(Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(log), input);
}

public static void FooInterface(ILogger log, string input)
{
    FooFn(log.Write, input);
}
```

rust:

```rust
use std::ffi::{c_char, CStr, CString};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo_fn(
    log: extern "stdcall" fn(log::Level, *const c_char),
    input: *const c_char,
) {
    let input = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(input) }.to_str().unwrap();
    foo_internal(&log, input)
}

impl log::Logger for extern "stdcall" fn(log::Level, *const c_char) {
    fn write(&self, level: log::Level, msg: &str) {
        let msg = CString::new(msg).unwrap();
        self(level, msg.as_ptr());
    }
}

mod log {
    #[repr(C)]
    pub enum Level {
        Verbose,
        Debug,
        Information,
        Warning,
        Error,
        Fatal,
    }
    pub trait Logger {
        fn write(&self, level: Level, msg: &str);
        fn verbose(&self, msg: &str) {
            self.write(Level::Verbose, msg);
        }
        fn debug(&self, msg: &str) {
            self.write(Level::Debug, msg);
        }
        fn information(&self, msg: &str) {
            self.write(Level::Information, msg);
        }
        fn warning(&self, msg: &str) {
            self.write(Level::Warning, msg);
        }
        fn error(&self, msg: &str) {
            self.write(Level::Error, msg);
        }
        fn fatal(&self, msg: &str) {
            self.write(Level::Fatal, msg);
        }
    }
}

fn foo_internal(log: &dyn log::Logger, input: &str) {
    log.information(&format!("received input \"{}\"", input));
    log.information(&format!("how's this for output"));
}
```

This all works fine for `ILogger`, because the whole interface is implemented in terms of one method / function pointer, but that won't work for other interfaces.

In general, I want to pass a pointer to the (presumably opaque) object itself, including the relevant vtable, and implement a corresponding trait for it in rust. Maybe the pointer would be unnecessary and I'd only need the vtable, but I'm not familiar enough with the low-level details of dynamic dispatch to be sure.
It should be an entirely polymorphic object, so I'll only be coupled to the interface that it implements.

Example (non-working) code:

C#:

```cs
[DllImport(dll)]
private static extern void foo_interface([SomethingToMarshalTheVtable]ILogger log, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)] string input);

public static void FooInterface(ILogger log, string input)
{
    foo_interface(log, input);
}
```

rust:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct AbstractLogger {
    pub object: *const Object,
    pub vtable: *const LoggerVTable,
}

extern "C" {
    type Object;
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct LoggerVTable {
    pub write: fn(*const Object, log::Level, &str),
}

impl log::Logger for AbstractLogger {
    fn write(&self, level: log::Level, msg: &str) {
        let vt = unsafe { &*self.vtable };
        (vt.write)(self.object, level, msg)
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn act_interface(log: AbstractLogger, input: *const c_char) {
    let input = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(input) }.to_str().unwrap();
    foo(&log, input)
}
```

Necessary caveat: I want to limit the scope of this to only borrowing from C#. I know that things get complicated when you need to pass ownership over FFI, and I have no intention do actually do that. If I've done that at all above, it was entirely accidental, and I'd like to be corrected.

Necessary disclaimer: I know unwinding over FFI is unsound, so those `unwrap`s should not be there. (famous last words) I'll fix it later.

Comment: It might help to know why this is needed, rather than message passing or some other IPC method? The .Net garbage collector is not going to be your friend here, you probably need to pin the memory, and have a known layout -- which would be more in line with a `struct` than a `class`?

Comment: Honestly, it's not needed. What I needed was to pass a serilog logger, and I've got a way to do that. But knowing an answer to this will serve me in future, as I work a lot with C# at my day job, and wish I could use rust. I can flesh-out the problem space a little more though. I'll edit the question

Comment: I've updated the question. Though having written all that out, it would probably be simpler and less error-prone to just use a struct of method pointers, instead of a fat pointer like I have above, unless c# has some really clever and simple solution up its sleeve.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to marshal the CLR-internal vtable directly. I'm not even sure how you would get access to it. Likely you'll need to pass a delegate to each interface method separately and build yourself a vtable on the Rust side as a struct of function pointers.

Comment: OT, but in case it's a useful perspective @ZoeyHewll, we do a boatload of Rust/C# interop in our codebase and started with broad/detailed FFI. Over time we have moved to (effectively) a client/server interface where the C# side sends text commands via FFI to Rust, which responds with (effectively) more text. JSON in both directions would work well. There's a bit more effort required on each side of the boundary to encode and decode requests/responses, but far less sketchy unsafe FFI surface area to worry about, and this in turn means we've been confident moving a lot more code to Rust. HTH!